# library not found for -lGTLTouchStaticLib

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-endpoints

I am updating my code for `GTLR` , to resolve the conflict with `GTL` and `GTLR` i deleted the `GTLTouchStaticLib` but still it is referencing in my project somewhere.

Because of that getting error  library not found for `-lGTLTouchStaticLib` .

How to fix this ?

Comment: Please check Link library with binary in target, where you found your lGTLTouchStaticLib file.

Comment: Thank you very much